# How can I turn random matrix into a table?

Tags: python, list, matrix, 2d, tabular

Here is the code I'm given.

```
import random

def create_random_matrix(rows_min, rows_max, cols_min, cols_max):
    matrix = []

    # generate a random number for the number of rows
    # notice that randint works differently from similar functions
    # you have seen in that rows_min and rows_max are both inclusive
    # http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint
    rows = random.randint(rows_min, rows_max)

    for row in range(rows):
        # add a row to the matrix
        matrix.append([])

        # generate a random number for the number of columns
        cols = random.randint(cols_min, cols_max)

        # generate a random number between 1 and 100 for each
        # cell of the row
        for col in range(cols):
        matrix[row].append(random.randint(1, 100))

    # done
    return matrix

def print_matrix(twod_list):
    print(twod_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    random_matrix = create_random_matrix(8, 12, 3, 7)

    print_matrix(random_matrix)
```

The code creates a random matrix like this:

> > > [[52, 23, 11, 95, 79], [3, 63, 11], [5, 78, 3, 14, 37], [89, 98, 10], [24, 60, 80, 73, 84, 94], [45, 14, 28], [51, 19, 9], [43, 86, 63, 71, 19], [58, 6, 43, 17, 87, 64, 87], [77, 57, 97], [9, 71, 54, 20], [77, 86, 22]]

But how can I change the code to output something like this instead?

36 83 35 73

28 11 3 45 30 44

39  97  3  10  90  5  42

55  73  56  27  7  37

84  49  35  43

100  20  22  95  75  25

58  81  26  34  41  44  72

32  23  21

31  37  1

95  90  26  6  78  49  22

5  17  31

86  25  73  56  10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple solution to your problem to print the members of a list of lists:

```
mymatrix = [[52, 23, 11, 95, 79], [3, 63, 11], [5, 78, 3, 14, 37], [89, 98, 10], [24, 60, 80, 73, 84, 94], [45, 14, 28], [51, 19, 9], [43, 86, 63, 71, 19], [58, 6, 43, 17, 87, 64, 87], [77, 57, 97], [9, 71, 54, 20], [77, 86, 22]]
for list in mymatrix:
    for item in list:
        print item,
    print
```

the output would look like:

```
52 23 11 95 79
3 63 11
5 78 3 14 37
89 98 10
24 60 80 73 84 94
45 14 28
51 19 9
43 86 63 71 19
58 6 43 17 87 64 87
77 57 97
9 71 54 20
77 86 22
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the way you print it:

```
>>> for i in random_matrix:
...   print " ".join(str(j) for j in i)
... 
52 23 11 95 79
3 63 11
5 78 3 14 37
89 98 10
24 60 80 73 84 94
45 14 28
51 19 9
43 86 63 71 19
58 6 43 17 87 64 87
77 57 97
9 71 54 20
```

And just for fun, in one line:

```
print "\n".join(" ".join(str(j) for j in i) for i in random_matrix)
```